# unexpected change of area

Tags: qgis, python, geometry

Selecting a vector layer and running the following script, I expect the total area of my feature-geometries to be the same at the end of execution.

```
from shapely.wkb import loads
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union

def getTotalArea(someLayer):
    area = 0
    for feature in someLayer.getFeatures():
        area += feature.geometry().area() 
    return area

layer = iface.activeLayer()
print getTotalArea(layer) # I want this to be the same area at the end of this script !!

# merge geometries
oldGeoms =[loads(feature.geometry().asWkb()) for feature in    
layer.getFeatures()]
un = cascaded_union(oldGeoms)
newGeom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(un.wkt)
print newGeom.area() # still the same area we started with, so far so good

#remove all previous features
layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures([f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures()])
print getTotalArea(layer) # zero now, because all Featrues are removed

#create and add new Feature, with merged geometry
newFeature = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())
newFeature.setGeometry(newGeom);
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([newFeature])
print newFeature.geometry().area() # just to be sure ... still the same geometry we started with    
print getTotalArea(layer) # what the ... !??
```

However the output (with one of my example layers) is:

5272.52221858

5272.52221858

0

5272.52221858

5272.52221858

5288.52221858

The last line of the script prints a different area than I expect (off by 16). Why ? Is it some kind of bug, or am I missing something important ?

It depends on the layer and the features that are processed, I do not always encounter that strange behaviour. But if I have a layer that gives this "error", I can reproduce it consistently.

Comment: I'd check the layer for any invalid geometries, self intersecting polygons, etc.